# SQL select from two tables, using a distinct value between the two IF it exists, otherwise only using value from the first table?

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables, with structures like this:

**roomlist**:

```
-room (unique)
-totalDesks
```

**userlist**:

```
-room (has duplicates)
-deskOwned
```

I need a SQL statement that will spit out the following:

```
room
totalDesks
desksUsed (COUNT(DISTINCT userlist.desk))
desksOpen (totalDesks-(COUNT(DISTINCT userlist.desk)))
```

I have this so far:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT roomList.room, userlist.room, roomList.totalDesks, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT userlist.desk) AS desksUsed, 
    roomlist.totalDesks - COUNT(DISTINCT userlist.desk) AS desksOpen     
FROM 
    roomlist, userlist 
WHERE 
    roomlist.room = userlist.room
```

The problem is that not all rooms currently have users in them.  If I have rooms A, B, C and D, but only records of people in A, B and C, it won't include room D in the result - even though room D has 5 totalDesks, none of which are taken.

How can I get a result that will still give me results on a room from roomlist, even if no records exist for that room in userlist?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a LEFT JOIN instead.  I assume you need to group by room as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     roomList.room, 
     userlist.room, 
     roomList.totalDesks, 
     COUNT(DISTINCT userlist.desk) AS desksUsed, 
     roomlist.totalDesks-COUNT(DISTINCT userlist.desk) AS desksOpen 
     FROM roomlist 
         LEFT JOIN userlist ON roomlist.room=userlist.room
     GROUP BY roomList.room, 
         userlist.room, 
         roomList.totalDesks
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest mocking this up in http://sqlfiddle.com/ it will be much easier to help you then

Comment: It was ment to be, but for some reason stack made it an answer.